# Google Maps API V2 Daily Usage

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am using [Google Maps Android Api V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) for maps. Is there any limitation of usage of maps in android?  I have read the doc mentioned by Google from here  [Google Maps Usage Limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits).
It's clearly mentioned that

> The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits

But still i am a little confuse and want a confirmation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the Quotas for Maps API is that a map load is defined as:

> A single map load occurs when:
>
> - a map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 when loaded by a web page or application;
> - a Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 by a web page or application that
>   has not also displayed a map;
> - a single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API; or
> - a single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View Image API.

from https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload

Therefore since a map load is not triggered by the Mobile API (Android or IOS SDK) then there is not a quota limit for the Mobile API's.  I'll ask my contacts in the Google Maps team for clarification though.

Comment: Thanks
Please clarify about it as google mention in its doc:
The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits.